# Joining 2 Database Tables Getting A Sum Value Output

Tags: php, mysql

I'm going to make this a little clearer as I've realised it's not as clear as it should be.

**Table One**

```
ID, COMPANY_ID, OPPORTUNITY, DATE_CREATE
```

**Table Two**

```
ID,ASSIGNED_BY_ID
```

What I am trying to do is add all the values in OPPORTUNITY for each ASSIGNED_ID.  COMPANY_ID in **table one** is the same as ID in **table two**.

So for example:

**Table One**

```
COMPANY_ID | OPPORTUNITY | DATE_CREATE 
1000       | 50          | 2013/09/19
1000       | 100         | 2013/09/18
1000       | 200         | 2013/09/18
1005       | 100         | 2013/09/18
1005       | 200         | 2013/09/18
```

**Table Two**

```
ID         | ASSIGNED_BY_ID 
1000       | 4
1000       | 4
1000       | 4
1005       | 2
1005       | 2
```

So I want a SELECT statement that will provide these results:

```
ASSIGNED_BY_ID  | OPPORTUNITY
4               | 350
2               | 300
```

I would like individual select statements per ASSIGNED_BY_ID.

How is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
SELECT t1.ID,SUM(OPPORTUNITY) AS total 
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.COMPANY_ID=t2.ID
WHERE t1.DATE_CREATE BETWEEN '$fromdate' AND '$todate' AND t2.ASSIGNED_BY_ID=1 
GROUP BY t1.ID
```

**UPDATE**

```
SELECT t2.ASSIGNED_BY_ID,SUM(OPPORTUNITY) AS total 
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.COMPANY_ID=t2.ID
WHERE t1.DATE_CREATE BETWEEN '$fromdate' AND '$todate' 
GROUP BY t2.ASSIGNED_BY_ID
```

Comment: What does the GROUP BY t1.ID actually do?  It seems that when I remove this part it provides me with an accurate figure but when it's in the statement it provides me with a figure far less than what it should be.

Comment: It groups the results for ID field and gives the SUM against individual ID. If you need SUM of all the OPPORTUNITY then group by is not needed.

Comment: I've edited the question to make it clearer as I don't think it was clear from the beginning.

Comment: Updated the answer as per new question. What you needs to do is group by ASSIGNED_BY_ID.

Answer (score 0):

Use this please

```
   SELECT SUM(a.OPPORTUNITY) AS total, a.ID FROM table1 a inner join table2 b on a.COMPANY_ID =    b.ID  WHERE a.DATE_CREATE BETWEEN '$fromdate' AND '$todate' AND b.ASSIGNED_BY_ID=1 group by a.ID;
```